# Crystal Reports not prompting for parameters

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a program to churn through some data that uses 3 reports.. recently our network admin upgrade a server to Win 2012 R2. That server is a slightly newer version of crystal reports. My program uses Version=13.0.2000.0.

Since the upgrade to the new server, my 3rd report, which relies on user entered parameter values no longer prompts the user for the values and shows a blank crystal report viewer. The report works fine locally on my machine.

Curious if anyone has run into this problem? Hopefully. Any ideas / Solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well after 2 days of searching a co-worker pointed me to this blog post -->

https://adilmca.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/visual-studio-2012-crystal-report-not-working-on-windows-server-2012-0x800a1391-javascript-runtime-error-bobj-is-undefined/

Add the report viewer folder to the project and copy in that bit to the webconfig to point to the new folder. I would like to know why this occured, and I will continue digging to figure it out - but for now the problem is solved. Hope this helps someone else.
Thanks.